# QSqlTableModel, QTableView удалить строку

Tags: qt

Мне нужно чтобы строка из QTableView при нажатии на кнопку удалилась (исчезла). При том что у меня стратегия стоит OnManualSubmit. То есть удаление из БД будет происходить когда я сделаю submitAll(). Но после удаления вышеупомянутой строки я могу нажать на отмену и повторно открыть ту же самую таблицу и строка должна быть на месте.

Я сделал удаление выделенной строки через QSqlTableModel::removeRow().

Получилось что удаление произойдет только после submitAll() и до этого строка просто помечается на удаление. Но мне надо чтобы она из QTableView исчезла.

Answer (score 1):

tableView->setRowHidden(row, true);
скрывает строку с индексом row

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте производный класс от QSqlTableModel, где переопределите rowCount() и data(), так чтобы они "не видели" помеченные к удалению записи.